# Connecting Azure Activity Log to Log Analytics instance using PowerShell

Tags: azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to configure Azure Activity logs to be forwarded to a Log Analytics instance using PowerShell? Essentially the same that can be performed using the Portal as outlined on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-activity-logs#configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the PowerShell cmdlet **New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource**.

Illustration:

```
New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource -ResourceGroupName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceResourceGroupName> -WorkspaceName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceName> -Name <NameOfThisOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource> -SubscriptionId <SubscriptionId>
```

For more information refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.operationalinsights/New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes it does, thanks so much! Do you happen to know how I can connect the AAD logs?

Comment: Check if the below Microsoft documentation links help to accomplish the ask regarding AAD logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-log-analytics and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-analyze-activity-logs-log-analytics

Comment: Sorry, was wondering how to connect AAD logs to Log Analytics using PowerShell - not the porta.

Comment: What value do I need to provide for the -Name parameter?  The Microsoft documentation on this cmdlet is horrendous.

Comment: You may provide any string value for -Name parameter. It's mentioned in the same article i.e., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.operationalinsights/New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: And the reason for that -Name parameter is, if you want to get and check already created Operational Insights Data Source(s) 
then you may use the cmdlet 'Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsDataSource' as shown below and check if a Operational Insights Data Source(s) with particular name already exist or not.

"Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsDataSource -ResourceGroupName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceResourceGroupName> -WorkspaceName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceName> -Kind AzureActivityLog"

I hope now it's clear and it helps!! Cheers!!