# How to connect Azure Activity Monitor to Log Analytics Workspace via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics, activity-monitor

How do I connect Azure Activity Logs to a Log Analytics workspace using an ARM template?  I can connect it via the portal:

[image]

Or using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.operationalinsights/New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

But I've searched far and wide and can't find documentation on how to do this with an ARM template (or whether it's currently possible).

I've also tried creating the connection and viewing the resource structure in the azure resource explorer (and by fetching the resource in powershell), but there's no difference in the json before and after making the connection

**UPDATE:**

I tried an arm template deployment based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/2015-11-01-preview/workspaces/datasources), which I applied like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "my-loganalytics-workspace-name/AzureActivityLog",
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources",
            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {},
            "kind": "AzureActivityLog"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it the deployment doesn't complete (has been running for 30 minutes) and has a vague error:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/template/operations/A886A53AFF9B2E6C",
    "operationId": "A886A53AFF9B2E6C",
    "properties": {
        "provisioningOperation": "Create",
        "provisioningState": "Running",
        "timestamp": "2019-03-25T13:54:32.2320046Z",
        "duration": "PT21M58.8224235S",
        "trackingId": "47915902-f795-482a-a408-de408cd78a30",
        "serviceRequestId": "8c153090-c33d-4819-b9c4-8226df6a861e",
        "statusCode": "InternalServerError",
        "statusMessage": {
            "Message": "An error has occurred."
        },
        "targetResource": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/my-log-analytics-workspace/dataSources/AzureActivityLog",
            "resourceType": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources",
            "resourceName": "my-log-analytics-workspace/AzureActivityLog"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working example template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-DDoS-Attack-Prevention/nested/microsoft.loganalytics/workspaces.json).

So my original template needed a different name (must include the subscriptionId) and a `linkedResourceId` in the `properties`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat('my-loganalytics-workspace-name', '/', subscription().subscriptionId)]",
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources",
            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "linkedResourceId": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/microsoft.insights/eventTypes/management')]"
            },
            "kind": "AzureActivityLog"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible using portal or PowerShell as explained here -> [Connecting Azure Activity Log to Log Analytics instance using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069660/connecting-azure-activity-log-to-log-analytics-instance-using-powershell/54071731?noredirect=1#comment97363867_54071731)

I have created it using portal or PowerShell and could get those details using PowerShell as shown in below screenshots, in which the ResourceId parameter shown the resource type 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources'.

[image]

[image]

So most probably it should be possible via ARM template way as well because I see a ARM template reference for resource type 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources' as shown here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/2015-11-01-preview/workspaces/datasources

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: The documentation at that link is lacking sufficient detail to be able to implement it.  The "properties" object in the resource has this description: "The data source properties in raw json format, each kind of data source have it's own schema."  That's not helpful, since there's no info as to what the schema for each data source is.

Comment: Knowing the resource type helped get me on the right track though.